# Date and time formats in Spanish

Tags: traducción, españa, tiempo

Is this an acceptable (or rather correct) way of writing date time in Spanish?

English version:

> As of Tuesday, October 20, 2015 4:32:11 PM EDT

Spanish version:

> El martes 20 de octubre de 2015 16H32' EDT

Comment: What context are you using this?

Comment: In my website the date time is localized. Just wanted to make sure what is shown above is correct.

Comment: So it is the date time alone, not within a sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>*Note I am not mentioning anything about the "as of" because I lack context for that.*</sub>

If you want to show the date time in your website, you may want to see what kind of approach you want to follow.

If it is just a header with the date, use it succintly:

> Martes, 20 octubre 2015 16:32

But if it is part of a sentence then you can add all the articles and prepositions:

> El martes, 20 de octubre de 2015 a las 16:32

---

Regarding the format itself, it may be interesting to read what Fundéu recommends on it: [horas, grafía](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/horas-grafia/)

Basically it states that if working with 24 hours, just use the numbers separated by either `:` or `.`, followed by an optional `h` (hours) --> `23:45` or `23:45 h`.

Comment: A little note on timezones: since we don't have many timezones here in Spain, we don't usually state the timezone when writing the time (I would say pretty much no one knows the names of our timezones), though we probably should. I guess other countries, like Argentina, are more used to it...